# WPF Control is not tracking the mouse movement on click and drag

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Sorry if this is a poor question, but I'm trying to get a click and drag effect on a control where the control will follow the users mouse movement as long as the left mouse button is pressed. I followed this tutorial first to get basic click and drag functionality https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh144799(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-7

I modified the code a bit to try and get the control to follow.

**Circle.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="DragDropExample.Circle"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DragDropExample"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         AllowDrop="True">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="TestStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" To="0"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Canvas x:Name="canv">
        <Ellipse x:Name="circleUI" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Blue"/>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

**Circle.xaml.cs**

```
namespace DragDropExample
{
public partial class Circle : UserControl
{
    private Brush _previousFill = null;
    private bool _isDragging;

    public Circle()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Circle(Circle c)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.circleUI.Height = c.circleUI.Height;
        this.circleUI.Width = c.circleUI.Height;
        this.circleUI.Fill = c.circleUI.Fill;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            DataObject data = new DataObject();
            data.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, circleUI.Fill.ToString());
            data.SetData("Double", circleUI.Height);
            data.SetData("Object", this);

            Point position = e.GetPosition(this);
            double x = position.X;
            double y = position.Y;

            Canvas.SetLeft(circleUI, x);
            Canvas.SetTop(circleUI, y);

            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, data, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnGiveFeedback(GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnGiveFeedback(e);

        if (e.Effects.HasFlag(DragDropEffects.Copy))
        {
            Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Cross);
        }
        else if (e.Effects.HasFlag(DragDropEffects.Move))
        {
            Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Pen);
        }
        else
        {
            Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.No);
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDrop(e);

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
        {
            string dataString = (string) e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat);

            BrushConverter converter = new BrushConverter();
            if (converter.IsValid(dataString))
            {
                Brush newFill = (Brush) converter.ConvertFromString(dataString);
                circleUI.Fill = newFill;

                if (e.KeyStates.HasFlag(DragDropKeyStates.ControlKey))
                {
                    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
                }
            }
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDragOver(e);
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
        {
            string dataString = (string) e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat);

            BrushConverter converter = new BrushConverter();
            if (converter.IsValid(dataString))
            {
                if (e.KeyStates.HasFlag(DragDropKeyStates.ControlKey))
                {
                    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
                }
            }
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDragEnter(e);
        _previousFill = circleUI.Fill;

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
        {
            string dataString = (string) e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat);

            BrushConverter converter = new BrushConverter();
            if (converter.IsValid(dataString))
            {
                Brush newFill = (Brush) converter.ConvertFromString(dataString);
                circleUI.Fill = newFill;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDragLeave(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDragLeave(e);
        circleUI.Fill = _previousFill;
    }
}
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="DragDropExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DragDropExample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Canvas>

    <StackPanel 
                Background="Beige"
                AllowDrop="True"
                DragOver="panel_DragOver"
                Drop="panel_Drop" Height="319" Width="517">
        <TextBox Width="Auto" Margin="2,2,413,2" Text="green"/>

        <local:Circle Margin="2"/>
        <!--<local:Circle Margin="2"/>-->

    </StackPanel>
</Canvas>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void panel_DragOver(object Sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("Object"))
        {
            if (e.KeyStates == DragDropKeyStates.ControlKey)
            {
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
            }
        }
    }

    private void panel_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Handled == false)
        {
            Panel _panel = (Panel) sender;
            UIElement _element = (UIElement) e.Data.GetData("Object");

            if (_panel != null && _element != null)
            {
                Panel _parent = (Panel) VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(_element);

                if (e.KeyStates == DragDropKeyStates.ControlKey && e.AllowedEffects.HasFlag(DragDropEffects.Copy))
                {
                    Circle _circle = new Circle((Circle)_element);
                    _panel.Children.Add(_circle);
                    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
                }
                else if (e.AllowedEffects.HasFlag(DragDropEffects.Move))
                {
                    _parent.Children.Remove(_element);
                    _panel.Children.Add(_element);
                    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

It's really pretty simple code, and when I click on the circle and move the mouse with the left mouse button pressed it jumps across the screen to the right and down. I'm wondering if I should use a storyboard or Transformation of some sort on the circle to get it to move. I'm sure it's just something simple I'm missing, but it's escaping me right now. I would greatly appreciate any advice.

Comment: `MouseDragElementBehavior` is your friend.

Comment: I don't see you translating the initial position into client coordinates or anything like that. The mouse position is (IIRC) screen, but the position you set on the Canvas is client. Does it "jump" if the window is at 0,0 on the screen? Anyway, I'd look into using a `Thumb` control; it does a lot of this for you, and [the DragDelta event](https://wpf.2000things.com/2012/12/19/715-using-the-thumb-control-to-drag-objects-on-a-canvas/) is easier to work with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18104074/424129

Comment: @EdPlunkett It jumps down and to the right if I don't move the window from when it's rendered by the a[[

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thumb does exactly what I needed it to! Thank you!